# It is possible to change or disable Date validator in jira

Tags: jira

I change calendar javascript to Hijri, But another problem comes up. It seems that a class (DueDateValidator.class) try to validate input date, while the number of days in month is different to georgian calendar. for example we have 31 days in second month of year but in georgian (february) it is 28 or 29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box option to cancel Jira's date validation. You could overwrite Jira's date validation, but I think it will be easier to use a `Free Text Field` custom field that will hold the date as a string. Then, add to the field js code that will hide this field and copy it's date to the `date` field.

To keep the right order when searching for issues, you can either use date mapping to keep the georgian calendar up to date, or store the dates in a sortable way (for example `YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM` - 201302161334) and order the results according to this field.

**UPDATE**

Simple example for Jira version 5.2.6, this will copy the text from field id `customfield_10001` to the `created` field:

```
AJS.$("#create-date").text(AJS.$("#customfield_10001-val").text().trim())
```

To search easily keep another text field and save the date in the following format :

```
year month day hour minute
```

All in digits. for example, today's Gregorian date would be:

```
2013 02 267 10 26
```

than, when searching for issues, for example to find issues created after today's date:

```
custom_filed  > "2013 02 267 10 26"
```

that sorting will work since it will sort issues first by year, than month, day, hour, minute.

Comment: thank you for quick response, could you please give me javascript code that hide filed and copy date text to date field?

Comment: that depends on your Jira version. I gave you example for Jira 5.2.6.

Comment: its work for me. thank you again. for second paragraph (To keep the right order ...) I don't understand What should I Do , Its possible to describe this procedure a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I stored date in text field by creating new custom field in system-customfieldtypes-plugin.xml filed but In search it only accept exact text not > or <

```
custom_filed  ~ "2013 02 267 10 26" It is acceptable but

custom_filed  > "2013 02 267 10 26" shows jQL error.
```